# Google map static api - combining two encoded polylines

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I am trying to get a static map using Google Static API and the image I want has two encoded polylines. The two polylines are working ok separately as follows but when I add them, I get a 404 error.

**Alaska**

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=600x300&maptype=roadmap%20&path=enc:_q%7bnIxywyWdxs%40xbuAiiD%7epq%40ivmAboa%40%7dbHtp%60Agmi%40pfpAetX%60faAgeU%7e%7eFkeq%40yrb%40dsEnom%40edTvieA%7b%7eTvgOusd%40w%7bd%40%7dRgzc%40ycpAnei%40qtNfvh%40gqf%40%60p%5bq%7bYlitBkza%40kkK%7bkj%40feIyztBprpBkxK%60diBaffAvs%7b%40sj%60%40Iqyc%40pdwAnjdAo%7eo%40d%7ez%40%7beQ%7cwMzpk%40mae%40r%7ecAjiHpau%40gnm%40n%5dyme%40xsa%40lgKzx%5dzxgAocg%40rk%5elx_C_%7d%60%40x%7cn%40tBbg_%40ywk%40hcnBy%7e%5d%7cho%40wdPtZogc%40jsdAq%7cMh%7bbAe%60V%60hv%40esXrv%60Bss%5df%60tAcvScus%40gwX_VccIfue%40hbY%7cteBcrHheqB%7blYz%7efBqoOps%60%40yyVl_wD%7bf%40xogA%60fKhiyCjdGvte%40gaU%7csh%40no%40hrm%40_eRjic%40efEn%60hA%7b_l%40%7cydCg%7cFnp%7d%40%60mWdpl%40vrWzzxAgi%5ddfU%7bqe%40eyrD%7dsXxxfAryGtx_AckXt%7dIck%60%40vmpBpcSnbn%40lsJzrcAi%60A%7expAjpl%40abKxq%5ccg%5bpmg%40zkc%40%7c%7ea%40%7bb%7c%40veVxtj%40upQftt%40daVbt%7d%40%7byEhshAm%7cLra%5dxaGh%60r%40dxYzdn%40xl%5cjrJvsCzcg%40flp%40h_qAsx%40tmjAlod%40%60of%40zpM%7em%7cC%7bqQj%7ek%40it_%40o_Q_oVmc%7eAshm%40%7cmzAoqp%40ae_%40ghb%40o%7cu%40qo_Awu%5dcsa%40%60h%5b%7d%60L%7dubAedp%40uzdCvea%40swhAc%7b%5csvq%40ueZnq%60A_%7dSql%5djlApryCjeM%60g%7c%40%7cwXttZz%7cEpg%7c%40tu%5dvn%7d%40%60kVdmHnmk%40x%7dxA%60%7eT%7bsMlc%60%40%7c%7e%7d%40zi%7b%40nf%5clqDpyx%40xbe%40nqHdpHj%7cqAbog%40pbp%40%60eHh%7c%7c%40rfm%40bg%60%40joNyp%5cqJ%7dyfAnvg%40yhmAr%7eVj%60TxqXpvt%40n%60%40f%7bi%40telAvmo%40xld%40tetArc%40nznAj%7c%5btyS%60yMz%60%7bArym%40bb_%40b%60%40l%7cl%40lwW%60qgAz%7dl%40k%5e%7efYlhf%40%7e%60%5bvzzAluYpfe%40ukQpqa%40d%7c%5dlcc%40xwJbhdAjxVzyd%40%7cfFfhi%40txZtk%5e%7cgHobv%40%60%60k%40rki%40vxKn%7crAxjLlxIf%7cYv_vE%7euMvkHlv%5df%7bdBxhFbvv%40nb%60%40nofAk%60%40v%7ct%40mqn%40yt%5cotA%7edl%40blh%40plRdzy%40xqt%40%7cdNjnq%40mnCdfp%40%7cgVroy%40g%7c%40vwr%40bs_A%7ckjBat%40fm%60Blh%5dxhs%40plMnew%40adD%7c%7cf%40g%7b%5dhnSkwO_%7dm%40kkk%40_b%5eo%60%40akg%40ci%5betvA_%7c%40%7bseA%7d%7bVsmoBo%7cd%40u%7dx%40%7db%7e%40oilAicf%40ypvA_rWoldCf%7cB%7bvs%40fuTygQ%7d%7bIusl%40wkaAg%7ba%40gsr%40%7difBu%7ds%40%7dc%7dCtoBwebAgld%40%7c%5e%7bno%40q%7bv%40snVkl%7b%40ghg%40qeiAm%7c%5dMabxCcep%40opf%40q%60hAmc%5enrFdip%40n%7bfEwto%40npyBf%7d_%40bgQbqh%40gu%5drsJrdeAcgaAt%7c%7e%40k%7b_%40dzaAvm%5crga%40%7df_%40fyhAeoWlcEhg%5ep_tA%7eu_%40tfqB%7exa%40xjbAkwPp%60q%40yhVkc%60%40o%7ed%40nyAe%7cy%40jet%40c%7di%40mbdAqs%7bAzvpAalf%40x%60p%40rw_%40htX%7ev%40%60yf%40zfXr%7chArsJdl%7bAs%7bExqkBytc%40%7e%7cMihItzd%40mxi%40ze%7c%40_nGtor%40at_%40zdmAaob%40%7dpy%40%7d%60i%40maEimn%40%7coZ%60rIlsiA_hc%40biLy%60Jv%60q%40%7b%7d%5e_nWcbYxejAyn_AgilAosa%40y%7dL_viAgnoBakoB%7bgyAop%5eom_B%7e%7eGqqnAzga%40yipAmwCczt%40ow_%40yxhAgjq%40_nkA%60xFwfeCcaJyhvAmps%40_ogAygyAnbh%40av%5evcw%40cmh%40ecyAclh%40%7ecY%7d%7bJdgu%40fpTb%7b%5esbBfuw%40hfTz%7b%60Bnd%5cvpgAnj%5bn_Qqbo%40njqBrpGzkQzkGxwwE%7csTpcsBic%5crjmFsg%5czeo%40u%60ZciL_dU%7cvt%40k%60XofIex%5ec%7bw%40_tIjbZo%7eNh%7e_Eq%7d%5ejltBoiTdqDqlYmdmBg_l%40w%60jCgbgA_mtGek%5eoqcEaaAmroBljmAj%60QpiXob%5covDareE%7e%7eJqaeAje%40udkBimi%40%7dpw%40%7esDcgcAcnWcqL_%7bJfjlAhhHfikAis%5e%7daGiig%40x%7ckAglAzuh%40gz_%40zdV_lEqv%7b%40fs%60%40klu%40ncU%60gJpmg%40kt_BwwFsko%40eqm%40vmkBg%7bn%40ung%40_gPjpY%7egMr%60fCuc%5czwqFykXpuA%7bi_Avt%7d%40%7bm%7bAvdsGi%7cHz%7chAcz%5e%7egfAcd%5cdmZquZsa%5bkq%7c%40%7dwBxdCeilDefMwvpE_dh%40qekCyc%5culs%40e%7cdBqfq%40cvhAiiaCmdZumyAbjEemrBqrNiz%7bA%7drb%40gxsBo%7dl%40ismBqwNqa%7cAnkPgkcBw_HadyBovUcofB%7d%60aAaifCaz%40yku%40rdWkgwDfzTkuFn%60UfkvA%7ebVkxWu%7c%7c%40gnbDxnVaepAnbf%40moGbgJghkAw%7cUc%7cw%40udF_j%7eBvbRmieEpbi%40xre%40njKo%7etBx%7e_%40_xaCmdOuje%40%60zHeerBczRso_Bt%7bCeheCdwb%40k%7etCozC%7dh%60Af%7cWsdlAb%60IykpJb_%5dsyrBf_Ds_pBa%7bKi%7b%5eyrUsedFfeTeogBdzbAy_%60GpjHkiqAbk_Fqh%40dxkFAjpyGk%40l%7eyD%5btjfIW%7cdrEM%60cmEkZbatCpXdkKqqeAyvKard%40lpVelyAi%7b%5c%7d%7ev%40alAarvBj%60z%40pqGhkZmqrA%7egZ_zNz_fBaqeEtc%60Ass%5di%7bo%40%7drxB%7bb%40wkn%40ms%7bAwnkAutCyvn%40%7doY%7bnzAram%40k%7bvAluZjxFxnZsdTjkEwuq%40vmUw%7bh%40zwt%40awl%40j%7eWo%7cnA%7eby%40awxAb%7bGb%7eMp%7el%40%7bzv%40do%7dBswvBn_x%40_m%7c%40h%7dUjvV%60nGgp%7c%40fza%40zeLj%7eKslo%40j%7cf%40ubFgfA%7dlp%40%60kg%40_x_BfoFanz%40lvWsv%7c%40pzRexG%7emBsx%7c%40hjh%40gwOj%7eZj%7cX%7cgc%40ctCp_y%40ws%5blcp%40lbm%40&key=

**Rest of US**

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=600x300&maptype=roadmap%20&path=enc:kvafGpppaNug%5dri%40esUy_pB~a%40sacBveE%7dzi%40bkQebb%40%7bmEwjc%40lb%40yutA%7dkMiqp%40_%7ca%40gew%40%7bbIymg%40ewk%40f%60DknXyaQ%7bzQ~%60c%40%7dw_%40au%40o_%60%40%7d%60mAqz%5bet%5bmqcAyoeBqa%5c__pAzqBklbAhd%40ej%60AeiCakyDgJ%7dzRvfAw%60wCq~%40_p%7dCahp%40uyYw%7cEazr%40%7deR_dt%40kkg%40wib%40w%60U%7dvn%40ii%60%40yoZufX%60iJin%7b%40icTmuOis%5cezu%40gwJcetCc%7cuClvGk%7cc%40xlUt~Ax%7bU%7dg%5dumSyb%7d%40sbJchdAx_u%40imsA%7crzEmz%40vzr%40jjCnhRsxhAbiz%40t%7dH%60vTmea%40zRi_%5bpgcA_ha%40bl_%40%7clg%40ttAx%7c%60%40jtRf%60g%40thB%7ctg%40vyb%40jht%40dsSrks%40xS%7chh%40%7dsPbfy%40tpg%40jmt%40bvP%7doIxhRxy%60%40vOfmg%40pxXhr%60B%60it%40thwAdh%60%40vn%5dj%60s%40t%7cYj%7c%5exzY%7cmf%40mzF~ylAjfi%40rcJeci%40pj%5empXd%7b~%40%7b%7c_%40phHenh%40anQ_%7bp%40byUkwM%60~%5clwhCeca%40gk%40rsi%40%60~oA_E%7c%7dy%40jeWxkZp%7dIjmcAqiChzT~yMbcuAv~%40jkoBlwd%40j%60rAl~Pico%40saBstaB_lWkty%40hqUgym%40hjWlty%40xbf%40lv_CbnOxmaBpsFjoiA%7bzJh~TvvRtp_%40%60%7cPafj%40bxTsbCbwgBtiVxpmArt%7c%40~tUdlf%40djp%40~xa%40uq_%40hmQqkOruw%40ogR%7crc%40%7cjv%40jbEz_p%40ydg%40zwEodThxdAgkDbsv%40n~Vzyp%40dea%40v_Zpbh%40na%60%40btFl~gAb%60i%40ynKfug%40%7bifA_uUuum%40m%7ci%40qep%40fz%5bgiMbnSk%7ca%40zcE%60%60Wpld%40eal%40%7cl_%40ypYycIe%7c%5e%7cvImgk%40mi%60%40m~t%40tcj%40fvNzfJr%7db%40omH%60%7d%5bnnWlg%60AiVpqZ_%7bWnb_AmhDxg%60%40giWb_NfyLj%7do%40%7bl%40doa%40p~O%7c%7bj%40lmAhxMoaXlvU~cDb_Hyzy%40v%60aAezV%60rgAfcFz%60Mhm%5elcK%60gaA%7coYmjHo%7cHswy%40reJiru%40fn%7b%40khIdiIvg_%40%60wn%40dlo%40ilJpmyAzqWc_Zjwd%40~%7bXb~W_%60~%40jmWnp%60%40x%60%60%40foRw_Ijbj%40d%7dPnwtAf%7df%40f%7bgAxmm%40%60fo%40v%7bo%40n%7cUl_AtltAn%7d%5d%60xrAvvq%40z%60t%40fp%7b%40ndSxt%60%40tvx%40%7cpQdaQrn%5cfft%40nd%5ctv%5ct%7dWvw_Ah%60%5ezcYb%7cg%40%60zhA~eRgWzjw%40~sw%40bdg%40jbHhv%60Bbon%40leo%40lvFl%7b_B_qMdp~A%7dcXpj%7bByvw%40l%7clBulkAn%7d~%40jvDbt%5eckFlmdAaub%40%60%7ckCerw%40%60lj%40%7deKtik%40zm%40td%7dA%7cxLfo%7c%40brBtwIjwUjoi%40%60pQvrbAftB_%7cIxwS%7cnCj%7bbAfcLhhs%40weSb_Qe%7cXkuIo%7d_Atx%60%40i%7dg%40da%60Aeid%40rxa%40ihg%40vcE_%7cX%60jNyaJf%7bd%40m~%5cfhEmoWb%7bTeplC%60mxA%7bicAgl%7c%40baCbvd%40xmTzq%5cy%60b%40%7caUkr_An%7b%40aKqdR%7drgAceTkzmBxw%60%40yyBt_%60%40y%7cT~z%60%40ilXbnHu%7bQpqb%40gp%5cfmActIlkWyy%5ebrRoli%40hmjA%60b%40xzn%40fkPv%7bQx%7bo%40~mxA~~Mzt_BuqUynBqrZfgSacu%40xk%7bAmx%5bncqAynE%60h%60A~eMlk%60CdlMdreA%7dd%5e%60vo%40imo%40z%7cD%60vt%40zg~%40thI%7cud%40apKjmzAbwPntnAdiTbj%5cd~c%40luhAfoYwi_%40qs%60%40cte%40~~Ui%7ba%40dxj%40%7cu%5chc_%40huh%40bqZczd%40d%60%40efa%40rkYcne%40tt%5e_nHhjRp%7bMa~Jnff%40kt%5ehdZqgSvgeAzsl%40%7ckiAwjb%40fwNykFrpj%40ny_%40pge%40h_G%7cuY%7bxf%40dw%7bAkaRqzUojMpnn%40ezr%40lj%5exlD~kl%40oaXpzElpTnv%7b%40f%7bT%7d%7cPp%60O%60%60i%40%7bpIv%7dw%40ybc%40lvlBzpC%7c%7daBxhL~a%5dheE%7cxx%40d%60b%40bayAgiJpn%5bagl%40gvGrdRrl%7b%40xv%5esvQdzc%40u_Btg%5elyX~xo%40d%7c~%40npl%40%60txA%60x%60%40ftnAj%60a%40lmj%40jwC%7cn%5dsdUzvTztb%40%7cqPvmf%40doo%40tp~%40lag%40tvtAd%7b_%40j%7diBnxGnch%40iyJpsk%40gxWfp%7d%40wHphU~jRm%60Hly%5bk~%5b~hb%40kzExgb%40r%7bCly%5cccDb%7dKly%40%7c_H_fBpbDvrBtvB_~BrrC%60TznDgfHhoF_hn%40hycBacJrf%7b%40y~lA%7cn%5ck%7be%40vwc%40%7bj%5byhCus%60%40jnNkv%5ckbCis%5bhdTuuBlpUcq%5bpo_%40yra%40~qI_u_%40tq%5cclZdeh%40gn%5bxdGsgl%40~%60_%40e~u%40vo%5cep%5dtoC%7bj%5b~eWase%40%60kq%40ijQt%7df%40kie%40hoYqoJzr%7cAxg%40lyd%40ujQ%60vn%40puUbxLzeCr~v%40vaj%40xlX%60y%7c%40zpOzpCb%7cPrge%40dxYpRrk_%40ip%5c%7cln%40orq%40li%7bBcpo%40b_cAykv%40rk%60%40gwp%40%60n%40ueh%40js%60%40apa%40tnFqia%40zui%40iwI%7cg%5b%7dod%40lyx%40cpgA~_lAikSnrp%40i~r%40%60fa%40i_Hre%5bm%60%40ho%7cHA~dJv%7cvAb%40oBj_sEAztBxIxbwI_%7dpAvuaG%7ba%60%40vckBsz%7c%40tdiEgaq%40fe%60Dukj%40obQ~dQx%7caGh_PxbmEjKpeCekYd%7dVg%60g%40~a%40yio%40h~Mkmh%40%60sa%40ohlAh%7cpB_kAl%7d%7d%40iiRkvBgmc%40f%7bWdcD~wv%40kh%5bxioAozSrnIcj%5efow%40v%5btl%7c%40wrK%7cds%40t~Czn_Am_Yv%60a%40ubr%40__Fivi%40d%7cBmlTbnLi~Mvse%40gj%5dkkD%7deJleYyba%40%7c%7b%5e%7dpFbbVowdBhlsAs%7dVpta%40uz%7c%40fuD%7da%60%40mnYg%7cWlmMowCdrn%40_zm%40hly%40m%7c%5ekYgt%5e~rUytq%40yLi~D%7d%7bSjwi%40efHmvMioe%40ksUjw_%40y%7cq%40qgLykKrrk%40jyt%40q%7bAe~Jpdk%40a~Ythm%40qeh%40jsDcpg%40ph%5eonUftf%40weYtmTsoi%40nkv%40oiZgcE%7dx%7b%40bzXq%7db%40%7dtJgpu%40tsOgat%40vpq%40qu%5djkp%40%7dqa%40r_HmptAmap%40gta%40k%5cukjA%7btPsts%40nuNykMd~Tipj%40cdGihTrvZqo~%40%7ckNghY_yGi%7cr%40jv%5eme%5e_tQqus%40kpMo%60w%40ya%5cqdp%40cvKi_eDeoT_t%60%40%7cs%40ik%7c%40yyPwzcBsbFy_o%40%7cqDo%7d%60AokJy%7bNti%5di%60h%40yg%60%40yq_A~ae%40c~ToaR%7b_U%60dc%40_hr%40nzZyhkAxuTutZnae%40%7b%7bx%40njNehg%40e%7dH%60ck%40ihbCjqHq%60nCmxHkmOz%7dTo%7ckAlo%7b%40%7dav%40g%7cv%40qcq%40svQf%60Yudf%40voGclZ~bXy%7cXq%7bTyna%40xqT%7bgTrxo%40a%7cUykDpLyumKW%7ddnJx%40shqHqDwbmF%60D%7dpaJfHs%60nFjIyveH%7bSmctJx%40euaA~A_wdE%5e%7bbvI%40gnzEpAsxaKnAogaFiBgetE%7dDkkcL%40gqjK~Esk%7dIeia%40kAunf%40ewAvbO%7bi%7c%40tcoAawZrtSzo%40zrNuaf%40%60cMef_CxkTuyFk%7dDg~~%40ywQmjh%40%7ctBczs%40vzu%40oxfCdfCklw%40xtf%40_g%7b%40jlL_tq%40uuE_mb%40gx%5esffA%60t%5cus%5bypBsjsB%60xWaft%40e%60Celr%40lla%40vpfAp%7bWn%7clB~jNtye%40%7ckq%40dxsAv~m%40t_%7b%40l~%60ArmwBbqSgyXesMq%60wA%7d%60f%40oobCzgf%40rfHxnTyiX~pOq%60%7d%40s%60Uq%7cnAguVkbb%40wpGokoAoknAaqgDomWyi%5dm%7bOigm%40w%60B_jiAdhPtwA%60ga%40dplAhim%40bfl%40~eKgdiBz%60R_ds%40vdw%40atn%40ww%40%7dtgAtxQmvZmbPsfiAm%7c%5butdAym%40gd_C%7dfMw~j%40p%7cImxk%40hk%60%40zqD~aT%7dpaBktPwra%40k%7dCi%7b%5bpgx%40caVd%60%5cicFngQ_m%60%40yuPej%7d%40xh%5eyxLosHlhtB~bHzxr%40iqVzuu%40pki%40%60tPyh%60%40zbq%40m%7bO%7c%7b_AjGjgc%40pgW~xZdyExdr%40gaEfzs%40~x%60%40%7cs_%40kuLdupAx%7cYdaJfyJhc%60A%60dhBr%7btAvr%5bfqB%7c_Dr%7dc%40dbl%40x__%40bjb%40thCoaSmym%40gje%40el%5de%7cKcyf%40iir%40%7bx_%40jgNqbd%40%60pVnqZ~hxAhnx%40vv_Av_FztMfxWtxj%40~nPnff%40kzD%60yrA%7ccg%40zxo%40uuCpbi%40gsVnoZ%7cjHr%7baAr%7cBdbk%40qw%5crro%40i~N%7c%7cb%40%7dqa%40joCgi%5b%7bpPqbbAe~b%40er%7c%40ckeAclr%40wck%40uxSavm%40_kG%7dafAziHaigB%60mv%40mwe%40s~Smhn%40ziO_bw%40m%60o%40qmeAmaFmmKq%60%5egpYii%40yrG%7bsq%40ivVgxj%40tiz%40zvGlwBwtRkub%40ktXyjaAivCctPkdaAsqg%40h~Ocjb%40k%7bg%40qtFg%7bYrvYgw%7b%40dmBaco%40~hXuuS%7czh%40yceCxbaAhdC~~LcaWtp_%40meH~%7cgArpJjbUphi%40xh%60%40tyExaZrc~%40~%7cn%40%60LfjLebr%40%7bbgAomjAc%7dQunbAdyNeqa%40h%7c%5dmqSriuB%7dqT~mo%40inTffgAfpTldIhvJ%7bgRtwh%40t%7dp%40hxPbvNdia%40blNjnKzl%5cha%40zky%40po%7b%40htt%40elbBqM%7bnh%40zlYk_n%40kfYwszA%60qDaes%40cjc%40g_z%40mhb%40%7dksAyqb%40e%7ccCkpo%40_qvBi%7bf%40mmfAusKmuf%40ymYcoRooQgde%40sn%7d%40lng%40&key=

I have tried using two path URL parameters and using the | to separate the encoded polylines but none of them seem to yield an image.

Answer (score 3):

The length of the combined URL I get is 10469.  The max allowed is 8192 per [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#url-size-restriction):

> **URL Size Restriction**
>   **Google Static Maps API URLs are restricted to 8192 characters in size**. In practice, you will probably not have need for URLs longer than this, unless you produce complicated maps with a high number of markers and paths. Note, however, that certain characters may be URL-encoded by browsers and/or services before sending them off to the API, resulting in increased character usage. For more information, see [Building a Valid URL](https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/overview#BuildingURLs).